# What is the meaning of "pet au pair"?

Tags: expressions, french

Granted, this looks french, I've seen this used and referenced in English. I see it used a lot with dog walking businesses or pet sitting companies, although I have no idea what it means.

Google translates it to "pet au pair" in English (doesn't translate anything) and Googling the phrase only brings up more pet sitting websites.

Comment: Did you Google *au pair*? Why not?

Comment: From a French POV, the expression doesn't make sense.  Someone could be _au pair_ and take care of pets instead of the more common children, but I've never seen a case and it is the person which is _au pair_, not the pet.  For the pet to be _au pair_, it is the pet which would have to work; I can see for instance an horse to be _au pair_ by an riding school if it is fed for instance in exchange for the fact that it is used by the pupils.

Comment: Can you quote a sentence from somewhere (give a link too) that uses this?

Comment: Sounds like it must be a dog walker who works in exchange for a room. The construction is like fish kabob: While kabob means meat, and shish means skewered, we understand what the fish dish will look like anyway. Strictly, the term should be *fish shish*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Should the first dish be *kabob shish* then? I've always called it *shish kabob* (or just *kabob*), so I would have said *shish fish* (except that sounds like I'm trying to silence some noisy fish).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Right you are, *shish fish*. Smoothly done. As for kabob shish, I am not second-guessing another language, which is free to place adjectives and nouns in their preferred order.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I'm not fluent in any language except English (allegedly), do not take my question from ignorance as authority in any language; but I do like to **eat** and *kabob* is delicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like it is an [au pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_pair) for pets.

> **Pet** au pair
>
> Typically, au pairs take on a share of the family's responsibility for <strike>childcare</strike> **pet-care** as well as some housework, and receive a small monetary allowance for personal use.